# Capturing recent worksheet change into variable

Tags: vba, excel

For a table like this:

```
   |  B   |   C    |  D   |   E    |   F
---+------+--------+------+--------+------
 1 | Name | Number | Fab  | Design | Hours
---+------+--------+------+--------+------
 2 | AAAA |   10   |   35 |  811   |  505
 3 | BBBB |   11   |  541 |   18   |  694
 4 | CCCC |   12   | 9622 |   81   |  181
 5 | DDDD |   13   |  626 |  848   |  111
 6 | EEEE |   14   |    6 |  821   | 6616
 7 | FFFF |   15   | 6262 |  862   |   60
 8 | GGGG |   16   |  306 |  941   | 6166
 9 | HHHH |   17   |  365 |  484   |    6
```

after deleting a cell in a column `B`, my code displays a message box asking the user if they're sure before deleting the entire row.

How do I get the value of the cell before it was deleted and pass it to another macro that deletes cells in another worksheet based on that value.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  ' If target column is B, is below the header row AND it's new value is blank then...
  If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 1 And Target.Value = "" Then
    ' Clear contents of row
    ans = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Delete......This cannot Be Undone !!!", vbYesNo)
    If ans = vbYes Then

'How do I select Column 2, Row active cell and copy the value?
'How do I make the value into variable YYY?

      Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete 
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to copy the value you just deleted - but you can't, because you just deleted it?

Comment: Yep, that is the exact problem.

Comment: Please see answer below - you can freeze worksheet change events, programatically use "undo" to put the deleted value back in the cell, get the value in to YYY then delete the row as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could get the value that had already been deleted is by utilising the "Undo" function, try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ans As Integer
    Dim YYY As String

    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 1 And Target.Value = "" Then

    ans = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Delete......This cannot Be Undone !!!", vbYesNo)
    If ans = vbYes Then

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False ' freeze WorkSheetChange event since you're about to UNDO a change
            .Undo ' undo the change
            YYY = Target.Value ' assign the deleted-undone value in to YYY
            Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete ' delete that row
            .EnableEvents = True ' re-enable all events
        End With
        MsgBox YYY ' now you have that value in YYY
    Exit Sub
    End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: No problem! It's a little "hacky" I think, using the undo function, I feel like it might lead to bugs at some point - I would probably re-invent the way people can delete rows - like maybe pressing "D" in a designated delete column or something... let me know if you run in to issues?

Comment: I called my other macro, TestDeleteRows after the first "End If" statement and am getting a compile error:Sub or Function not defined. Why is it doing this even though I know it is defined?

Comment: Not sure unless I could see the full code - is it a `Private` function / sub?

Comment: It is the same code as above so its still a private sub. BTW how have you been formatting your comments?

Comment: If `TestDeleteRows` is a `Private` routine, try changing `Private` to `Public` and see if that works - depends where the routine is being called from, a module, a form, a worksheet object or the workbook object... it can be a bit confusing. Also - I'm formatting `Code` in comments using the ``` backtick (left of the 1 number on UK keyboard) - just put it either side of a ``word``. For large question formatting you can highlight code and press CTRL+K